# Can the digits of $\pi$ be represented by a single integer?

Tags: pi

I guess what I am really asking is, can an integer be constituted of an infinite non-repeating sequence of digits? Can you take all the digits of $\pi$ and store them in a single integer (even if we don't know how to write that?)

Comment: No. An integer number is a finite number hence it cannot have an infinite number of digits (non repeating or periodic).

Comment: The question, perhaps, is what you mean by "store".  One might argue that $960$ encodes all the digits, because it it stands (in some encodings) for the letter "$\pi$".